# How to fix garbage characters in viewer made by Viewer API of Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying Autodesk forge and I could make a viewer with it.
I upload Autodesk Revit file which has a lot of japanese parameter.
the viewer properly work.The model and parameters can be watch in it.
But the some value of those parameters became garbage characters.
(parameter name display proper Japanese word)

Anyone know how to fix them?

Comment: Can you share an example, seems to be a bug in the translation rather than a viewer issue.

Comment: what encoding are you using? can you ensure that you are using some variation of unicode throughout the entire data flow, e.g. UTF-8? can you examine the display at each step of the process to determine at exactly which point something goes wrong?